# generating mouse button click in linux

Tags: linux, qt, click, mouse

I'm trying to generate mouse click. I need it to my app, it must simulate mouse click.

```
QMouseEvent *klik = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, QCursor::pos(), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, klik);
QMouseEvent* klik2 = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, QCursor::pos(), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, klik2);
```

But it not working. It must work on linux, I found many examples for windows but anything for linux not working :(

sorry for my bad english

[EDIT]

I have little problem with QTest. Here are screenshot with compilator [errors](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61452937/qt.png)

Comment: In what way isn't it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [QTest::mouseClick](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qtest.html#mouseClick) which according to docs simulates mouse clicks.

for example in my MainWindow's constructor:

```
button = new QPushButton("testPushButton", this);
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(clickedButton()));
QTest::mouseClick(button, Qt::LeftButton);
```

And as yankee2905 said you have to add **testlib** to your .pro file.

In addition I tried to use your code, and when I changed position and receiver of the click it worked just the same as with testlib.

```
QMouseEvent *klik = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, button->pos(), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(button, klik);
QMouseEvent* klik2 = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, button->pos(), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(button, klik2);
```

Comment: +1 But, including a full module, and test oriented, to do something that should work with a postevent, inst that hammer a nut?

Comment: thanks but I need simulate mouse click outside my app window. I'm trying to write bot who clicking in fixed by user position. It's possible to write something like that?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to send QEvents outside Qt Event loop.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, looks like you haven't added "testlib" to your qmake file. You'll need that to begin using the QTest components.

Something like this:

```
qmake test.pro QT+=testlib
```